# How to get Cumulative Sum In Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have a query result like below...

| trx_id | Opening | qty_plus | qty_minus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | 1000 | 0 | 50 |
| 3 | 1000 | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | 1000 | 40 | 0 |
| 5 | 1000 | 0 | 300 |

I Want the resul like below

| trx_id | Opening | qty_plus | qty_minus | closing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 100 | 0 | 1100 |
| 2 | 1100 | 0 | 50 | 1050 |
| 3 | 1050 | 10 | 0 | 1060 |
| 4 | 1060 | 40 | 0 | 1100 |
| 5 | 1100 | 0 | 300 | 800 |

Comment: This question cannot be answered unless there exist another column (not shown) which maintains the _order_ of the transactions.  Does such a column exist?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please check the question again.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive total:

```
with recursive totals as (
  select trx_id, opening, qty_plus, qty_minus, opening + qty_plus - qty_minus as closing
  from the_table
  where trx_id = 1
  union all
  select t2.trx_id, p.closing, t2.qty_plus, t2.qty_minus, p.closing +  t2.qty_plus - t2.qty_minus
  from the_table t2
    join totals p on p.trx_id = t2.trx_id - 1
)
select * 
from totals
order by trx_id;
```

The drawback is the join condition that assumes no gaps in the `trx_id`. Maybe this is possible with window functions as well, but currently I can't think of a way.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=25948ef1bee46d404c39bfe333586c04)

Comment: #a_horse_with_no_name - THANK YOU VERY MUCH... it's working well.